# Does VS 2015 still support Win32 dialog box editing with Toolbox?

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2015, toolbox

I'm trying to create a dialog box for an old-fashioned Win32 project. This was working fine under VS 2010, but in VS 2015, the Toolbox no longer seems to include classic controls (Edit Box, Button, Radio Button, etc.)

The "Dialog Editor" section has only one option, and it's grayed out:

[image]

All the other categories are for .NET, WPF, Silverlight, etc. and are not applicable to my project.

If I right-click and select "Choose Items", I get all the fancy new stuff, but nothing about the old school dialog components:

[image]

Can anyone explain how to get the Toolbox to show something I can use? I would hate to have to edit the raw `RESOURCE.RC` text.

Comment: I'd say you didn't select the appropriate options for desktop development when you installed VS2015. Install it again and double-check your selections.

Comment: Brilliant! That did the trick (the Toolbox also has to be reset). I just went with the defaults when I originally installed it. I never would have thought that VS2015 would have omitted such fundamental options.

Thank you very much  :o)

Comment: Microsoft are (were) trying to kill off desktop development, the default VS2015 options were a reflection of this :(

Comment: @Jonathan Evil Microsofties! ;-)